# Translate digits to word in PAGES (MAC)

Tags: javascript, macos, numbers, applescript

I am using PAGES where I have to write numbers in words in a column of table. E.g.:

```
123=One Hundred Twenty-Three
```

Is it possible to write a custom function for such conversion for PAGES; something similar to Microsoft Excel?

I have seen JavaScript solutions for this purpose but I do not know how to apply it with MAC. Can someone help? I use `OSX 10.12.1` with `Pages 6.0.5`.

Answer (score 1):

You want `NSNumberFormatter`. e.g. Using [AppleScript libraries](https://github.com/alldritt/applescript-stdlib):

```
use script "Number"
use script "Text"

set N to 123

capitalize text (format number N using word format for locale "en_US")

--> "One Hundred Twenty-Three"
```

BTW, if you find these libraries useful, please file a duplicate [feature request](http://openradar.appspot.com/28465563) to `bugreport.apple.com` asking Apple to adopt them in macOS 10.13.